# Is there an error in the docs on class aliasing?

Tags: php, class, alias, autoload

On the [docs page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) on `class_alias` function we read:

> class_alias — Creates an alias for a class
>
> bool class_alias ( string $original , string $alias [, bool $autoload
>   = TRUE ] )
>
> Creates an alias named alias based on the user defined class original.
>   The aliased class is exactly the same as the original class.
>
> Parameters
>
> original
>
> The original class.
>
> alias
>
> The alias name for the class.
>
> **autoload**
>
> **Whether do autoload if the original class is not found.**

Well, so under what condition the class that's being aliased is autoloaded? When `$autoload` is set to `true`? Ok, but why the description of this parameter says that autoloading is to take place "if the original class is **not** found"? How can PHP autoload a class it can't find?

Comment: Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to put it would be:

> Whether to autoload if the original class is not *loaded*.

That means, if the class definition is currently not known, because its file has not been `include`d. That's when a class is "not found". In that case `class_alias` can invoke the registered autoloaders which will (hopefully) automatically include the file where the class is defined.

Comment: Or "Whether to autoload the original class if it's not already loaded."